# JMX issue with DataStax OpsCenter Agent

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

We're running an 8 node DSE cluster (just Cassandra) divided among two datacenters. Everything is working fine apart from the agent on one node which stubbornly refuses to cooperate.

Here is the version info:

> Cassandra 3.0.9.1346 
>   DSE 5.0.3
>   OpsCenter 6.03

All nodes have upgraded SSTables and have been repaired.

Here is the log:

```
  INFO [async-dispatch-47] 2016-11-08 14:33:13,811 Starting system.
  INFO [async-dispatch-47] 2016-11-08 14:33:13,832 Starting DynamicEnvironmentComponent
  WARN [async-dispatch-47] 2016-11-08 14:33:13,845 Exception while processing JMX data: java.lang.NullPointerException
 ERROR [async-dispatch-47] 2016-11-08 14:33:13,845 Error starting DynamicEnvironmentComponent.
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.java.io$as_relative_path.invoke(io.clj:404)
    at clojure.java.io$file.invoke(io.clj:416)
    at opsagent.environment.collection$cassandra_yaml_location__GT_install_location.invoke(collection.clj:118)
    at opsagent.environment.dynamic$dynamic_env_state.invoke(dynamic.clj:61)
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__4527.invoke(core.clj:2492)
    at opsagent.jmx$create_jmx_pool_with_config$wrapper__11504.doInvoke(jmx.clj:221)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630)
    at opsagent.environment.dynamic$add_dynamic_state.invoke(dynamic.clj:143)
    at opsagent.environment.dynamic.DynamicEnvironmentComponent.start(dynamic.clj:168)
    at com.stuartsierra.component$fn__8838$G__8832__8840.invoke(component.clj:4)
    at com.stuartsierra.component$fn__8838$G__8831__8843.invoke(component.clj:4)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at com.stuartsierra.component$try_action.invoke(component.clj:116)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:401)
    at opsagent.config_service$update_system$fn__20056.invoke(config_service.clj:200)
    at clojure.lang.ArraySeq.reduce(ArraySeq.java:114)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6518)
    at opsagent.config_service$update_system.doInvoke(config_service.clj:194)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at opsagent.config_service$start_system_BANG_.invoke(config_service.clj:219)
    at opsagent.config_service$fn__20133$fn__20134$state_machine__4719__auto____20135$fn__20137.invoke(config_service.clj:245)
    at opsagent.config_service$fn__20133$fn__20134$state_machine__4719__auto____20135.invoke(config_service.clj:242)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:940)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.ioc_macros$run_state_machine_wrapped.invoke(ioc_macros.clj:944)
    at clojure.core.async$ioc_alts_BANG_$fn__4884.invoke(async.clj:362)
    at clojure.core.async$do_alts$fn__4838$fn__4841.invoke(async.clj:231)
    at clojure.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel$fn__1215.invoke(channels.clj:262)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 INFO [async-dispatch-47] 2016-11-08 14:33:13,848 Finished starting system.
```

Any ideas?

Edit: here is the requested additional info.

> The node's addresses are as follows: 
>   listen: 10.2.2.22
>   rpc: 10.1.2.22

---

All ips are private and SSL is disabled because the DCs are connected via a VPN.

---

```
# nodetool status

Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.72  12.14 GB   256          ?       a15c57e1-3c53-4d4f-9df9-29945b9f1c88  RAC1
UN  192.168.1.92  11.36 GB   256          ?       9820b96a-a3c6-460f-839b-5dabc89313a0  RAC1
UN  192.168.1.82  11.67 GB   256          ?       f9c13cb0-ee44-4ce2-ac7e-14ec1f7c1d23  RAC1
Datacenter: DC2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.2.2.32     11.04 GB   256          ?       bfe86bb3-d272-4946-ac8a-e176fe9f8e64  RAC3
UN  10.2.2.22     11.29 GB   256          ?       c8694e93-0d8a-41b4-82a3-6c450497e8ec  RAC2
UN  10.2.2.52     11.46 GB   256          ?       e941faf1-ad5b-46a7-8857-bdf9dd2a3459  RAC5
UN  10.2.2.42     10.9 GB    256          ?       7bbd2397-a3bc-4cfe-9c03-334186e7e0dd  RAC4
UN  10.2.2.12     5.29 GB    256          ?       bf7a0587-2b09-47d6-b6d5-24e1422318b9  RAC1
```

---

> # address.yaml
>
> stomp_interface: 192.168.1.31
>
> use_ssl: 0
>
> cassandara_conf: /etc/dse/cassandra

---

> root@anc-t2:~# netstat -lnt Active Internet connections (only servers)
>   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address
>   State       tcp        0      0 10.1.2.22:9160          0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp        0      0 10.1.2.22:9042          0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp        0      0 10.2.2.22:7000          0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17600         0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp        0      0 10.2.2.22:8609          0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54882         0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17603         0.0.0.0:*
>   LISTEN      tcp6       0      0 :::6900                 :::*
>   LISTEN      tcp6       0      0 :::61621                :::*
>   LISTEN      tcp6       0      0 :::9910                 :::*
>   LISTEN      tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*
>   LISTEN      tcp6       0      0 :::17500                :::*
>   LISTEN

---

```
# opscenterd.conf

[webserver] port = 8888 interface = 0.0.0.0
# The following settings can be used to enable ssl support for the opscenter
# web application. Change these values to point to the ssl certificate and key
# that you wish to use for your OpsCenter install, as well as the port you would like
# to serve ssl traffic from.
#ssl_keyfile = /var/lib/opscenter/ssl/opscenter.key
#ssl_certfile = /var/lib/opscenter/ssl/opscenter.pem
#ssl_port = 8443

[authentication]
# Set this option to True to enable OpsCenter authentication.  A default admin
# account will be created with the username "admin" and password "admin".
# Accounts and roles can then be created and modified from within the web UI. enabled = False

# To help us better understand the needs of users and to improve OpsCenter, OpsCenter
# reports information about itself and the clusters it manages to a central DataStax
# server.  This information is reported anonymously, and potentially sensitive
# information, such as IP addresses, are hashed in a non-reversible way:
# http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/help/statsReporterProperties.html [stat_reporter]
# The interval setting determines how often statistics are reported.  To disable
# reporting, set to 0
# interval = 86400 # 24 hours
```

---

```
# cluster.conf

[jmx]
username = 
password = 
port = 7199

[agents]

[cassandra]
username = 
seed_hosts = 192.168.1.72
password = 
cql_port = 9042
```

---

```
cqlsh:OpsCenter> desc KEYSPACE;

CREATE KEYSPACE "OpsCenter" WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '1', 'DC2': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".rollup_state (
    node text,
    name text,
    res int,
    avg float,
    histogram blob,
    max float,
    min float,
    ts timestamp,
    type int,
    value float,
    weight float,
    PRIMARY KEY (node, name, res)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name ASC, res ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.1
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"version": [5, 2, 1], "info": "OpsCenter management data."}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 0
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".events_timeline (
    key text,
    column1 bigint,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '8', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.25
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".settings (
    key blob,
    column1 blob,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '12', 'min_threshold': '8'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 1.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".rollups60 (
    key text,
    timestamp varint,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, timestamp)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 0
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.25
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".backup_reports (
    week text,
    event_time timestamp,
    backup_id text,
    type text,
    destination text,
    deleted_at timestamp,
    full_status text,
    keyspaces text,
    status text,
    PRIMARY KEY (week, event_time, backup_id, type, destination)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time DESC, backup_id ASC, type ASC, destination ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".rollups86400 (
    key text,
    timestamp varint,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, timestamp)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '8', 'min_threshold': '2'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 0
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.25
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".bestpractice_results (
    key text,
    column1 varint,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 0
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.25
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".pdps (
    key text,
    column1 text,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 0
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.25
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".rollups7200 (
    key text,
    timestamp varint,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, timestamp)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '8', 'min_threshold': '2'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 0
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.25
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".events (
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    action bigint,
    api_source_ip text,
    column_family text,
    event_source text,
    "keyspace" text,
    level bigint,
    message text,
    source_node text,
    success boolean,
    target_node text,
    time bigint,
    user text
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '12', 'min_threshold': '8'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.25
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';

CREATE TABLE "OpsCenter".rollups300 (
    key text,
    timestamp varint,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (key, timestamp)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = '{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 1]}'
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '16', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 0
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.25
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Can you add the Keyspace definition of your OpsCenter keyspace and also the output of `netstat -lnt` on this node? Also add the agent's `address.yaml` and the opscenter `opscenterd.conf` and `cluster.conf` file please?

Comment: @markc I have added the requested info and also the output of nodetool status.

Comment: thanks for the details. I can see that the node is listening on jmx (7199) on the loopback IP. Can you tell me if you have more than one `cassandra.yaml` on this node. Use `find / -name "cassandra.yaml"` as sudo or root

Comment: @markc Apart from the correct one, there is another in /usr/share/dse/templates/cassandra/cassandra.yaml. Bear in mind, all the nodes have exactly the same configuration, apart from (obviously) hostnames and ips. This is why I think it could be down to corrupt data in the OpsCenter keyspace. What would happen if I just dropped the keyspace and started again?

Comment: you can drop the OpsCenter keyspace ok but you will lose historical stats. I've opened a chat room here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127649/opscenter to avoid our comments dragging on too long